# SQL Group by calculation

Tags: sql, ms-access

Thanks in advance..

```
SELECT width, thickness, lengthfeet, lengthinch, Sum(nos), Sum(areasqft)
FROM materialsdetails
WHERE materialcode='" & Me.txtMaterialCode.Text & "'
GROUP BY width, thickness, lengthfeet, lengthinch
ORDER BY width, thickness, lengthfeet, lengthinch
```

I am using the above code to get the sum of the fields 'nos' and 'areasqft' by group.

In the 'transactionthrough' column, (Please see the image)[image] I have entered 'Purchase', 'Issue', 'Return' and 'Damage' as data.

Actually, instead of `Sum(nos)` and `Sum(areasqft)` I just need the value as 
Purchase - Issue + Return - Damage with the same `Group by` fields in the query.

Comment: What's the error?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to negate the values for Issue and Damage using the below if statement within the sum.

```
    SELECT  width
        ,thickness
        ,lengthfeet
        ,lengthinch
        ,SUM(nos*iif(or(transactionthrough="Issue",transactionthrough="Damage"),-1,1))
        ,SUM(areasqft*iif(or(transactionthrough="Issue",transactionthrough="Damage"),-1,1))
FROM materialsdetails
WHERE materialcode = '" & Me.txtMaterialCode.Text & "'
GROUP BY    width
        ,thickness
        ,lengthfeet
        ,lengthinch
ORDER BY width
        ,thickness
        ,lengthfeet
        ,lengthinch
```

Answer (score 0):

First, group by TransactionThrough:

```
   create view byTT as 
    SELECT 
    transactionthrough,
    sum(width) as width, 
    sum(thickness) as thickness,
    -- etc for each column you care about
    FROM materialsdetails
    WHERE -- whatever where clause you want
    group by transactionthrough;
```

Then negate:

```
create view negByTT as 
select 
transactionthrough,
-width as width, 
-thickness as thickness
-- and for each other column
from byTT;
```

Then sum by the transaction types you care about, with the appropriate sign:

```
select sum(width), sum(thickness) from (
  select width, thickness
  from byTT where transactionthrough = "Purchase" 
    or transactionthrough = "Return" 
  union select width, thickness
  from negByTT where transactionthrough = "Issue"
    or transactionthrough = "Damage" 
);
```